# How to orient dryer receptacle when NM comes down, dryer cable comes up, and recepticle only has knock-outs on bottom?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, dryer, mounting

I got a NEMA 14-30 for a new electric dryer circuit, and the receptacle I got was this Leviton surface mounted one:

[image: receptacle in question]

The receptacle has black plastic on 4 sides (shown in the image) and the other two sides (bottom and back) are metal with knock-outs.

My problem is the circuit's NM 10/3 cable is coming down a cinder block wall, having been stapled to wood joists overhead. Meanwhile, the dryer's plug will be coming up that cinder block wall, tending to hang downward. If this receptacle is installed with a vertical orientation, either A) the NM has to be ran below the receptacle and make a sharp turn - affixed to cinder blocks - before coming up into the receptacle's knock-outs on bottom, or B) the dryer plug has to be hung upside-down adding tension to the cables long-term.

I could've bought a [flush-mount receptacle](https://www.homedepot.com/p/ELEGRP-30-Amp-125-250V-NEMA-14-30R-Flush-Mount-Power-Outlet-Single-Straight-Blade-Range-and-Dryer-Outlet-Grounding-Black-2105S/317611242) and a 2-gang box to mount on the wall, avoiding this whole issue. Now I know, but I also already bought this wall-mount receptacle and opened its packaging, I'd rather not have it go to waste if possible.

One idea is to mount this receptacle horizontally, so that the NM enters from the left side and the dryer plug is inserted horizontally, with minimal tension on both cables. Or, plan D, just go buy the 2-gang box and flush-mount receptacle to do this right and try donating the wall-mount receptacle to a ReStore.

[image: Sketch of 3 options]

**Is option C look suitable for long-term use and code compliant in the U.S.?** Option B looks bad for the dryer cable, and option A looks unusual to me and like extra strain on the NM 10/3 cable.

This will be mounted around 5' above ground in a mostly-dry basement, right above the dryer.

Answer (score 4):

I'd go with A or C. For comparison, mine is horizontally mounted like C, but with the NM coming straight in from the right (panel is to the right side on the same wall).

NM at this size has a small bending radius. It shouldn't be a sharp 90, but your diagram looks fine - each 90 should have a few inches to turn between the horizontal & vertical staples. As suggested by Ecnerwal, you could use A with a big U (single staple in the horizontal section instead of two staples) and that should eliminate any concern about bending radius.

Comment: I'd go with A but make one big smooth U turn, not two little L turns with a straight section between them.

Comment: How high on the wall are you planning to place this? I think the modern standard for dryer (and washer?) is to locate the receptacle above the top of the appliance so that it can be unplugged by reaching over the top with the appliance in place.

Comment: @JimStewart high enough for what you described - reaching over the top of the appliance to unplug it. Something like 5 to 6ft up the wall.

Answer (score 4):

Big-box stores have *ridiculously generous* return policies.  This is a fair exchange for them being overpriced.   If you got it at a big-box store, return it with pride...

And then, use separate box and receptacle so you can "decouple" plug orientation from cable entry.

- A [receptacle](https://www.homedepot.com/p/ELEGRP-30-Amp-125-250V-NEMA-14-30R-Flush-Mount-Power-Outlet-Single-Straight-Blade-Range-and-Dryer-Outlet-Grounding-Black-2105S/317611242)
- A basic  4x4 x 2" deep box with corner screws.
- A Raco 810C or other domed cover that fits the box. If the cover has mashed-flat corners, it will automagically pick up ground via the flush metal-metal contact with the box.
- A cable clamp fit for 10/3 cable
- A short machine screw (bolt) sized 10-32. Does not need to be green.

Land the ground wire on the box's ground lug, not the socket (code requirement, and 1 less wire to wrestle).  Pre-attach the socket to the domed cover with screw and nut.  Then mount the domed cover any orientation you want. Leave yourself 8-11" of wire length inside the box.

One other thing: if your wire is coming down the wall without physical protection, it needs that.  The usual approach is to use 3/4" EMT conduit with [a connector](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Halex-3-4-in-Electrical-Metallic-Tube-EMT-Set-Screw-Connectors-5-Pack-26272/100163157) to enter the steel box.  Or [offset connector](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Halex-3-4-in-Electrical-Metallic-Tube-EMT-Offset-Compression-Connector-03907/100138782) if you can get the 10/3 wire through it. The top of the 3/4" pipe can just end with the cable coming out... however it must be deburred.  Cut it with a hacksaw NOT a tubing cutter, will make deburring much easier.  A standard stripping multi-tool is shaped like a wedge (when closed) to be used for deburring.

Normally it is forbidden to slide conduit over wires, but here we are not using conduit as a wiring method, just as a random pipe to provide damage resistance.

Comment: Thanks for the added useful info. I'll get the right receptacle and armor the length of the run down the wall, which would be more difficult with the extra turns in option A or C anyway.

Comment: Where the EMT conduit ends, shouldn't there be something to seal the opening of that tube, or does the connector to enter the steel box take are of that? I figure if I have NM coming out of the vertical tube, or even an elbow on the tube, it is a pathway for debris to enter the 4x4" box.

Comment: @cr0 nope, nothing needed.  And yes, it is - so if you used it in a wood shop or similar with a big dust problem, you'd probably need to plug it in some way. I just watched a government investigation video about dust explosions, seems the typical thing is a *small* explosion e.g. inside a machine sends an air shockwave through the shop, which shakes some of the cumulated dust off rafters and pipes. It raining down fills the shop with dust, and that causes the big explosion.  The cure is fastidious cleaning. I'm on board with that now, boy howdy!

Comment: Wow, noted. Not in a wood shop, but in an area that will collect cobwebs. There's always electrical tape to help keep the box clean, but I don't think it'd be a safety problem in this case.